# irreducible etale cover of a blowup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\rightarrow Y$ be a smooth morphism of schemes and consider the blowup of the fiber product along the diagonal, $W:=Bl_{\Delta}X\times_Y X$.

a.Does there exist a collection of **smooth** morphisms of schemes $X_i\rightarrow Y_i$ such that

1.the schemes $W_i:=Bl_{\Delta_i}X_i\times_{Y_i} X_i$ are **irreducible** and

2.there exist morphisms $W_i\rightarrow W$ ,such that $\{W_i\rightarrow W\}$ is an **etale** cover?

[Here $\Delta_i$ denotes the diagonal of $X_i\times_{Y_i} X_i$.]

b.**Same question with the additional assumption that $Y$ is smooth.**

In case $Y$ is singular, the answer in a. is negative, see Will Sawin's answer below.

Comment: What are you denoting by $W$?

Comment: Sorry, $W$ is the blowup of fiber product along the diagonal $W=Bl_{\Delta}X\times_Y X$, I'll edit the post.

Comment: Can't one take $Y_i$ an etale cover of $Y$ and $X_i = X \times_Y Y_i$? Fiber product and blow-up are both etale-local constructions, so everything will just be a base change from $Y$ to $Y_i$, hence etale.

Comment: @Will Savin:Why are the resulting schemes irreducible?

Comment: What does the index $i$ mean?

Comment: @Laurent Moret-Just a set of indices corresponding to the cover morphisms. I'll edit the post to make it clearer

Comment: @matthew: I didn't see that part of the question. The answer is not always. Take $X = \mathbb G_m$, $Y=\mathbb G_m$, with the map the squaring map. Then the fiber product is the disjoint union of two copies of the base, so any base change will be irreducible.

Comment: @Will Sawin: The $X_i\times_{Y_i} X_i$ need not necessarily come from a base change $Y_i\rightarrow Y$

Comment: @matthew: Well the answer is not always for my contruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the nodal cubic curve and let $X$ be its finite etale double cover. Then $X \times_Y X$ is just a union of two copies of the finite etale double cover. Blowing up changes nothing.

You have a slight problem here - the finite etale double cover is union of two $\mathbb P^1$ which intersect at $0$ and $\infty$. It has no etale cover by any irreducible  schemes, because each irreducible scheme must map to only one of the two $\mathbb P^1$s, but any etale neighborhood of either $0$ or $\infty$ intersects both $\mathbb P^1$s.

So I think no $W_i$ work, which means the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you, Will. I was originally interested in the case where $Y$ is smooth, which I didn't mention in the hypothesis. I'll edit the post to include this case, too.